# Why does the mean of this recursive sequence converge to $-Ω$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion, chaos-theory

Let $a > 1$ and $a≠e$

For the recursive sequence

### $a_{n+1}=\frac{\ln \left(a_n^2\right)}{2}$

(In other words recursively applying the operation $\frac{\ln \left(a^2\right)}{2}$)

The values I get appear to be chaotic, however taking the mean of all these values does seem to produce a convergence to $-Ω$ where $Ω=W(1)$

For example for $a=2$ and taking the mean of 67108864 iterations, the value I get is $-0.5690610554745104$ which is $-Ω$ to 2 decimal places, however this inaccuracy may be in part due to the level of accuracy of the python program I used which would have rounded to a number of decimal places at each iteration.

I am aware that *if* the original sequence were to converge, it would converge to the solution of $ln(−x)=x$ which is indeed $-Ω$ , however the original sequence does *not* converge, so my question is 
*why does the mean of all the numbers in the chaotic sequence converge to this value, despite it appearing to be chaotic?*

Comment: You might be interested in reading about Césaro series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean

Comment: I have looked at them, but I'm not sure, since the operation is recursive, that the mean can be shown by a Césaro series in the form $\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^na_i$